# Jenkins stages with multiple agents

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm having an issue with the pipeline if I want to define the agent for a specific stage.

```
def call(Map pipelineParams) {
    pipeline {

        environment {
            // Environment variables for Docker
            DOCKERCREDS = credentials('odyssey-artifactory-token')
            COMPONENT = 'listener-publisher-service'
            REGISTRY_PATH = 'com.csg.ops.it.prf'
            REGISTRY = 'docker-dev.odyssey.rowini.net'
        }

        options {
            disableConcurrentBuilds()
            timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
        }

        agent none

        stages {
            stage('Docker') {
                agent {
                    label 'docker'
                }
                steps {
                    sh '''
                                docker build -t $REGISTRY/$REGISTRY_PATH/$COMPONENT:$POM_VERSION . --force-rm=true
                                docker login -u $DOCKERCREDS_USR -p $DOCKERCREDS_PSW $REGISTRY
                                docker push $REGISTRY/$REGISTRY_PATH/$COMPONENT:$VERSION
                                docker rmi $REGISTRY/$REGISTRY_PATH/$COMPONENT:$VERSION
                                docker logout $REGISTRY
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
11:03:09  org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
11:03:09  Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.checkContextAvailability(StepDescriptor.java:266)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:296)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:193)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
11:03:09    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor294.invoke(Unknown Source)
11:03:09    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:03:09    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
11:03:09    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
11:03:09    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
11:03:09    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
11:03:09    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
11:03:09    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
11:03:09    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
11:03:09    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
11:03:09    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
11:03:09    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:158)
11:03:09    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
11:03:09    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
11:03:09    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
11:03:09    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
11:03:09    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
11:03:09    at runJenkinsPipeline.call(runJenkinsPipeline.groovy)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:431)
11:03:09    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:5226)
11:03:09    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.collect(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:3446)
11:03:09    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.collect(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:3463)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:429)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(ModelInterpreter.groovy:78)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:476)
11:03:09    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
11:03:09    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
11:03:09    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
11:03:09    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:78)
11:03:09    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor288.invoke(Unknown Source)
11:03:09    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:03:09    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
11:03:09    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
11:03:09    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
11:03:09    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
11:03:09    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
11:03:09    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
11:03:09    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
11:03:09    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
11:03:09    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
11:03:09    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
11:03:09    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
11:03:09    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
11:03:09    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
11:03:09    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
11:03:09    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
11:03:09    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
11:03:09    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
11:03:09    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
11:03:09    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
11:03:09  Finished: FAILURE
```

But if I define the agent outside the stages I don't get any error.

```
def call(Map pipelineParams) {
    pipeline {

        environment {
            // Environment variables for Docker
            DOCKERCREDS = credentials('odyssey-artifactory-token')
            COMPONENT = 'listener-publisher-service'
            REGISTRY_PATH = 'com.csg.ops.it.prf'
            REGISTRY = 'docker-dev.odyssey.rowini.net'
        }

        options {
            disableConcurrentBuilds()
            timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
        }

        agent {
            label 'docker'
        }

        stages {
            stage('Docker') {
                steps {
                    sh '''
                                docker build -t $REGISTRY/$REGISTRY_PATH/$COMPONENT:$POM_VERSION . --force-rm=true
                                docker login -u $DOCKERCREDS_USR -p $DOCKERCREDS_PSW $REGISTRY
                                docker push $REGISTRY/$REGISTRY_PATH/$COMPONENT:$VERSION
                                docker rmi $REGISTRY/$REGISTRY_PATH/$COMPONENT:$VERSION
                                docker logout $REGISTRY
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked the documentation about the Jenkins pipeline syntax, but I don't see any issue with my code. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see this error because the `credentials` helper method used inside the `environment` block requires the `node` context in a given execution context. You can see this by temporarily commenting out this part of the code and your initial pipeline will not fail for that reason.

You can solve this problem by defining `environment` block inside the `stage` that runs on the `docker` node:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        COMPONENT = 'listener-publisher-service'
        REGISTRY_PATH = 'com.csg.ops.it.prf'
        REGISTRY = 'docker-dev.odyssey.rowini.net'
    }

    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
    }

    agent none

    stages {
        stage('Docker') {
            agent {
                label 'docker'
            }
            environment {
                // Environment variables for Docker
                DOCKERCREDS = credentials('odyssey-artifactory-token')
            }
            steps {
                sh '''
                                docker build -t $REGISTRY/$REGISTRY_PATH/$COMPONENT:$POM_VERSION . --force-rm=true
                                docker login -u $DOCKERCREDS_USR -p $DOCKERCREDS_PSW $REGISTRY
                                docker push $REGISTRY/$REGISTRY_PATH/$COMPONENT:$VERSION
                                docker rmi $REGISTRY/$REGISTRY_PATH/$COMPONENT:$VERSION
                                docker logout $REGISTRY
                    '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Szymon, it is working now. Where can I find documentation about it?

Comment: The fact that pipeline steps (or helper methods) have to be executed inside the executor context is more or less common sense - I don't remember if the documentation states anything about it. There's one troubleshooting page that describes a problem caused by the missing executor (https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402585187483-How-to-troubleshoot-hudson-FilePath-is-missing-in-a-Pipeline-run) and I think this is the only place that explains it.